# webpack: copy a file without changing its contents

Tags: webpack

I am deploying my project to surge.sh

surge.sh needs a 200.html file to enable routing for (sub-)pages of single page apps

My file looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="gs.1.0.0.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="gs.1.0.0.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I load it using

```
import twohundredPage from 'copy!./200.html'
```

or

```
import twohundredPage from 'file?name=200.html!./200.html'
```

the resulting file looks like this:

```
module.exports = __webpack_public_path__ + "9802140cc82d486c4b933fc3da03da99.html"
```

and does not work on surge.sh which is a cdn

How can I load a file without changing its contents? Or in other words: **just** copy it?

**edit (2015.06.01)**

I have found no solution to the question.

But I managed to solve my issue like this:

By not hosting on surge but instead on a virtual server with hapi.js I didn't need to copy a 200.html file any more (and could configure hapi.js to let my index.html i.e. its script handle 404's). This was a good thing anyway because a virtual server from digitalocean.com has a response time of 20ms (in my case) as opposed to 300ms at surge.sh!

By using `react-favicon` (my project uses React) I could reference the favicon.ico in my code > no need for a favicon in a file named favicon in the root of the project any more.

Answer (score 0):

When you import your file via the [`file-loader`](https://github.com/webpack/file-loader), it is copied over to your output folder – by default, `output.path` in your config. You can configure the output path and the output filename in the [loader options](https://github.com/webpack/file-loader#filename-template-placeholders). The import simply returns the url of the file as `output.publicPath` + filename.

If you only need to retrieve the raw contents of the file, you can use `raw-loader`.

Comment: i need to control the name AND that the content of the file stays raw. The loader-options of file-loader let me control the name but not raw content. raw-loader lets me control raw content but not the filename (at least it is not documented)

Comment: The contents of the file will stay raw with file-loader: it will emit a file alongside your bundle, and the file itself will be represented by its url in your bundle. In other words, requiring the file from within the bundle will yield its url, which will point to the emitted file itself.

Comment: yeah (and thanks a lot for helping!) but this does not work for favicon.ico and 200.html on surge.sh which is a CDN: both files are not referenced from the code. The CDN relies on them beeing in the root folder of the project and being the raw files, not links

Comment: Webpack is module bundler, and works off of the module dependencies.  It sounds like you would be better served by running a node script to copy some necessary files as part of your build.

Comment: @bendman Your comment got me out of my box-thinking, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This can be achived using the [HtmlWebpackPlugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-webpack-plugin).  This isn't the real intent of the plugin, but it does work well for your purpose.

First install the plugin:

```
$ npm install html-webpack-plugin@2 --save-dev
```

Then in `webpack.config.js`, include the plugin:

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  ...
  plugins : [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template : './src/index.html',
      hash     : false,
      filename : 'index.html',
      inject   : false
    })
  ]
  ...
};
```

Note how `inject` is set to `false` above.  This will prevent any static assets from being injected into the html file.

Answer (score 0):

Just drop the `file!` prefix:

```
import twohundredPage from './200.html'
```

Only 1 file will be emitted and it will contain the **original file contents**. The returned value (`twohundredPage` in your case) will be the url to the emitted file.

**Edit**

A possibly better solution is to **specify the name url parameter in your webpack config file**:

```
loaders: [
    {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
        loader: "file-loader?name=assets/[path]/[name].[ext]"
    }
]
```

It looks like this retains the original file contents in the emitted files. You can then use the `file!` prefix in the `import` statement of your source file:

```
import twohundredPage from 'file!./200.html';
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found [CopyWebpackPlugin](https://github.com/kevlened/copy-webpack-plugin) useful to do this.